# Can't read query string if default index file name is omitted?

Tags: iis, asp-classic

Is there an issue with IIS or ASP Classic where *Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING")* returns blank if no default file name is given in the URL? On my local developer machine, I can do

```
http://localhost/xslt/?opcs/abc
```

which returns "opcs/abc". However, on our ancient web server, it returns nothing. I have to explicitly give it the default file name in the URL. Like so

```
http://localhost/xslt/default.asp?opcs/abc
```

While nothing too major, it is a little bit of a annoyance. One way I can maybe think of remidying the problem is have Javascript read the URL and return everything after the ?.

Unfortunately, I do not know what version of IIS or ASP we are using.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like a bug, I never experienced that when I used to do a lot of ASP. Make sure you are patched up to the latest version.

Comment: I know for a fact that the server is not patched. It is running Windows NT and I've been told that they will not update it. Request.QueryString does not return anything either unless I specify the default file name. :(

Comment: Write your own functions then, to be sure.

Comment: I don't follow. Write my own functions for what? AFAIK, there is no other server side way to get the full URL requested.

Comment: You're right, I thought SCRIPT_NAME included the querystring and you could parse that, but it doesn't. I really think that server needs to get patched or decommisioned, for security reasons more than anything else.

Comment: I've gone ahead and accepted your answer. Thank you for your time and help. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're running IIS 4.0, this may very well be the case. So you're really stuck with this ancient piece of software (and probably hardware) ? :)